# trouble requiring unique input in c#?

Tags: c#

I need to request 10 numbers from the user as individual inputs. Each number must be between 10 and 100, inclusive.

Compare each number to the last one entered to determine if it is a duplicate. If it is, ask the user for a different number.

Output each number to the screen once you have determined that all conditions are met.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String userNumber;
          int userNumberInt;
          // declare a variable to save the previous
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Enter your Number:");
              userNumber = Console.ReadLine();
              userNumberInt = Convert.ToInt32(userNumber);
              if ((userNumberInt <= 100) && (userNumberInt >= 100))
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Your Valid number is" + userNumber);
                  // set previous to the usernumber
              }
              // else if(previous == userNumber)
              // another invalid situatuion just like below
              else
              {
                  Console.WriteLine("Invalid Number"};
                  i--; // giving another chance
              }
          }
          Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework? Shall the comparison to check for dupes only be to the previous value (no two same numbers one after another), or to all previously entered values (not two same numbers at all)?

Comment: And your question is? Please state clearly what the code you have does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specific_ difficulty you are having getting it to do that. See [ask] for additional advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way

Comment: what if the user inputs 10,22,12,10,... do you have to re-aks the user if he inputs again a **10**?

Answer (score 0):

Just do that the comments state...

```
// declare a variable to save the previous
```

Should be:

```
int previous = 0;
```

Then:

```
// set previous to the usernumber
```

Should be:

```
previous = userNumberInt;
```

Ajust and fix you condition:

```
if ((userNumberInt <= 100) && (userNumberInt >= 100))
```

Should be:

```
if ((userNumberInt <= 100) && (userNumberInt >= 10) && (userNumberInt != previous))
```

Outputting the numbers is left as an exercise... ;)

Comment: why would you decrement on the valid ones? if you get an invalid number, decrementing basically cancels that iteration and you have a fresh one to try again.

Comment: @AlexandruPupsa Yeah, I didn't pay attention to the direction of the loop, my mental model was counting from 10 to 0 ;)

Comment: I did as you said but now I'm getting the following error,

Comment: I did as you said but now I'm getting the following error,Severity Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'previous' on line 21.